# Copying cells without detailed rows

Tags: excel, ssrs-2008

I've created a report via SSRS with groups and exported to excel. In excel, each of the groups have a drilldown into the detailed rows. Is it possible in Excel to copy the groups only, and not the detailed rows?

Answer (score 0):

http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/copy-visible-cells-only-HA010244897.aspx

There's an option for copying visible cells only.